# Apache Tika PDFParser returns NoClassDefFound after importing pdfbox dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies, pdfbox

I'm trying to develop an application for extracting pdf contents, and I have imported the apache tika dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
    <version>1.12</version>
</dependency>
```

to obtain the PDFParser class, which works on its own for any instantiations in my code.

However, for dealing with scanned documents, I tried importing the the pdfbox dependency from Maven but upon IntelliJ downloading the dependency I receive the NoClassDefFoundError for any instances of PDFParser, even if I don't import any classes from pdfbox at all.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/exceptions/CryptographyException
    at Starter.main(Starter.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.CryptographyException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

The code that I run in both cases is very straight forward for the testing this.

```
import org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser;

public class Starter {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("THIS IS A TEST");
        PDFParser stuff = new PDFParser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use current versions, and like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-parser-pdf-module</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This will also import the PDFBox dependencies.